# Parsing HTML in javascript ?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

all

I have a HTML input :`<h5><font face="times new roman, times, serif" size="7" style="color: #ff9696; ">Sample</font></h5> 
  <ul> </ul>`

I want to extract everything and pass to javascript variables. For example, 
font name, size, style color. Can I use RegEx?

I have tried this but no use:

```
<html>

    <script>
        var input = '<h5><font face="times new roman, times, serif" size="7" style="color: #ff9696; ">Krishanthan</font></h5> <ul> </ul>';
        var div = document.createElement('div');

        div.innerHTML = input;

        var size = div.getElementsByTagName('size')[0];
        var text = size.innerText || size.textContent;

        alert(text);
    </script>

</html>
```

Please give me some suggestion...

Thanks.

Comment: Use one of the [Javascript HTML Parsers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+html+parser) that are already available.

Comment: if you have to parse arbitrary HTML, than you cannot use regular expressions.  If you are using a small subset of HTML constructs, then maybe, but it depends on exactly what features of HTML you are maintaining.  If you want more help, you need to give us more details about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It seems you have to learn a bit more about the DOM. `size` is an **attribute** of the `font` element, it is not a tag. Get a reference to the `font` element and use `getAttribute` to access the attribute.

Comment: Wouldn't an inline style attribute in a font tag cause the universe to implode or something? @Gobi, read up on more recent HTML practices. Font tags have been considered bad practice for close to 10 years now. They were replaced by CSS which is what you're putting in the style attribute.

Comment: ... the inline style attribute which is also considered bad practice in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you are treating `size` like an element, whereas actually it is an *attribute* of the `font` element.

```
var input = '<h5><font face="times new roman, times, serif" size="7" style="color: #ff9696; ">Krishanthan</font></h5> <ul> </ul>';
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = input;

var fontEl = div.getElementsByTagName('font')[0];
var size = fontEl.getAttribute('size');

alert(size);
```

Comment: Thank-you so much yeah that works...........!!!!! It seems like I am very poor in DOM :(. can you suggest books for learning HTML DOM from basic... Thanks again